# why Kontsevich-Soibelman stability condition is a generalization of stable bundle condition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Just as the title, I head from a lecture. 
Could any body explain this in a detailed way?
Thanks.

Central charge is defined on page20 of 0811.2435, which I think comes from physical definition of 
central charge: as a linear map from weigth lattic to complex plane, satisfy some stability condition.

stable bundle is defined as in wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_vector_bundle

Comment: in a more concrete way: why deg(E)/rank(E) of a vector bundle E 
satisfy definition of central charged defined by KS.

Comment: It would be nice if you would write out the definition of a central charge, or at least link to it.

Comment: I'd say you should include as much detail in your question as you would hope for in an answer. (You can edit your question.)

Comment: Kontsevich-Soibelman stability is a modified version of Bridgeland stability. A good survey for Bridgeland stability and how its related to $\mu$-stability (usually attributed to Mumford not to Hitchin)
can be found in Bridgelands overview article "spaces of stability conditions" math.AG/0611510.